# how to point to the correct image giving the correct path

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to PHP and I am trying to bring the images into my css. Before i had it under a folder called `images` and i called it as shown in the code below, but now using cake php I am not sure how the path should look like
mystyles.css

```
.divtop
{
  width :1200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image:url('../images/topbanner.png');
  vertical-align:top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

but now the image resides in the `app/webroot/img` folder, how should i change that path so that it finds it?

Comment: You can't call the PHP in your CSS file.  I think you're going to have to hardcode your path at this point.  I've been struggling with how to get the relative path in a situation like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would depend on where your css folder is located, but assuming that it is in app/webroot/css, you would need to use url('../img/topbanner.png')

Comment: i got it thank you so much :), it just needed a server restart.. weird but it worked

Answer (score 0):

When pointing to images you are giving the location relative to where the CSS file sits

Comment: can you provide an example , i would really appreciate it.., I have tried different paths and nothing

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would create a folder in /webroot/img/ for css files that you need solely for CSS purposes.  It just make sense to keep all your images in as centralized as possible.

As long as you have your server configured so that webroot is actually the webroot, this is probably your best bet.

Additionally, you could create an images folder within your webroot/css/ folder.